How to get the MaxDequeueCount in the .NET function code
I am implementing an Queue triggered Function App. I want to access the maxDequeueCount value (defined in the host.json file). My code is roughly as follows:
// maxDequeueCount = ??

[Function("Function1")]
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%QUEUE_NAME%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] byte[] queueItem, string id, long dequeueCount)
{
  try
  {
    DoStuff();
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (dequeueCount <= maxDequeueCount)
    {
        HandleError1();
    }
    else
    {
        HandleError2();
    }
  }
}

While I can pass dequeueCount as a function parameter, I cannot find a way to get the maxDequeueCount value.
I am aware there is a FunctionContext which I can pass as a function parameter (as below):
public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%QUEUE_NAME%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] byte[] queueItem, string id, long dequeueCount, FunctionContext context)

However, when I reach the if statement in my catch block, it is a null object. Do I need to perform some other configuration to be able to use this information?

Can you try with IConfiguration instead of FunctionContext.

@Pavan I'm not sure what you mean, sorry. Did you mean another interface rather than IConfiguration?

IConfiguration is the standard interface for accessing configuration in .NET applications, including azure functions

Not sure how do use it, but docs don't mention such setting for host file.

@MichałTurczyn See here for extension methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#host-json

@WillSutton I am able to get the maxDequeueCount in host.json by using IConfiguration. check this Image

I have created Queue trigger function with runtime stack .NET 8.0 isolated.
When i send a message from the queue got triggered the function successfully and getting DequeueCount and maxDequeueCount by using below code and configuration.
Function1.cs:
public class Function1
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    public Function1(IConfiguration configuration, ILogger<Function1> logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("firstqueue", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage1")] byte[] queueItem, string id, long dequeueCount)
    {
        // Retrieve MaxDequeueCount from host.json
        int maxDequeueCount = _configuration.GetValue<int>("queues:maxDequeueCount");

        _logger.LogInformation($"MaxDequeueCount: {maxDequeueCount}");
        _logger.LogInformation($"DequeueCount: {dequeueCount}");

        try
        {
            // Your main logic here
            DoStuff();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (dequeueCount < maxDequeueCount)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Handling error, retrying...");
                HandleError1();
            }
            else
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Max retries reached, moving to poison queue...");
                HandleError2();
            }
        }
    }

    private void DoStuff()
    {
        // Your processing logic here
    }

    private void HandleError1()
    {
        // Handle retry logic here
    }

    private void HandleError2()
    {
        // Handle poison queue logic here
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
    {
        config.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();

host.json:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "queues": {
    "maxDequeueCount": 5
  }
}

local.settings.json:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage1": "your-storage-connection-string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  },
}

Output:


Assuming you're using the Azure Functions Isolated Worker Model, you can change the type of your first parameter byte[] queueItem to QueueMessage queueItem
Each message should keep track of their own DequeueCount which is available as property on the QueueMessage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.models.queuemessage?view=azure-dotnet
The QueueMessageConverter in the Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker is taking care of binding the data passed to the function, into the QueueMessage automatically
EDIT:
To get the Value of the maxDequeueCount things will be a little more tricky, but as pointed out in the comments - you could try inject access to the host.json via IConfiguration, as the functionContext does not seem to provide access to those:
var host = new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, configBuilder) =>
{
    configBuilder.AddJsonFile("host.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true); // add this, to get access to host.json values
})
.Build();

and afterwards you could access it by injecting into the function like this:
 public class Function1(IConfiguration _configuration)
 {
     [Function("Function1")]
     public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("%QUEUE_NAME%", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] byte[] queueItem, string id, long dequeueCount)
     {
         var MaxRetryCount = _configuration.GetValue<int>("extensions:queues:maxDequeueCount");
         try
         {
             DoStuff();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             if (dequeueCount <= MaxRetryCount)
             {
                 HandleError1();
             }
             else
             {
                 HandleError2();
             }
         }
     }
 }

I'll go through the SDK code, to see if there's a other/easier way - but above should actually work.

I can already access the dequeueCount through the function binding, but I am trying to get the maxDequeueCount as it is set in the host.json file. Apologies if it was not clear.

Sorry - that's on me, missed this while reading. Let me check - changes are that, you won't be able to, as that usually runs on the functions invocator (who observes the queue) and then spawns workers to process the messages. But let me update the answer once I went through the source :)
